# Why does my function in python adds headers improperly?

Tags: python, csv, header

So, I have this function that makes files, in this case i'm doing .csv files. In the function I want to add the feature to add a header in the new written file. However, it seems that when it writes the file, the new header row is added to the previous row instead of moving that first row down to add the header row(see picture).

[image]

Here is my code:

```
def fileMaker(name, data):
    header = ['UTC Time','ALtitude']
    newFile = open(name,'w')
    newFile.write(",".join(header)+"\n"))
    for row in data:
        for each in row:
            newFile.write(each)
        newFile.write('\n')
    newFile.close()
```

If you can help get the header in the first row and move the old first row onto the second row, and second row onto the third row and so on... It would be much appreciated  seriously! If the question needs formatting please don't hesitate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `str()` on a list, it will return literally what you see. E.g.:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> str(a)
'[1, 2, 3]'
```

What you want is to use the `.join()` function with on a string and join the list:

```
>>> a = ['1', '2', '3']
>>> "".join(str(a))
'123'
```

Note that if those were normal integers, it would raise an error:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> "".join(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found
```

In your case, you can actually use this:

```
newFile.write(",".join(a)+"\n")
```

This will separate each value by a comma.

Comment: I have ony modified the function with this newFile.write(",".join(a)+"\n") and the file that comes out has no header...

Comment: which newFile.write() do you change the first one or the second one?